# Drupal: displaying warnings

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can I disable warnings for my users in Drupal (and keep them on only for the administrator) ?

thanks

Comment: Feature request here https://www.drupal.org/node/2743119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this yet in Drupal 6.
[An issue has been created for this.](http://drupal.org/node/278665)

However, you can disable all on-screen warnings by going to Administer > Site configuration > Error reporting as stated on the [Book page for Securing Information from Visitors](http://drupal.org/node/244642). Errors will still be viewable by the roles given permission to do so by going to: Admin > Reports.

Comment: isn't there an easier way ? I mean.. maybe by removing a specific permission to the authenticated user, the warnings are not displayed anymore ?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem so by the conversation in the issue I posted. It seems that warnings are always shown in the developer environment and in the production environment it's switched off.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the [Better messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_messages) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Better Messages is a very simple module that provides "Popup-like" Drupal messages.
>
> Better Messages intends to let you control where and how you want to see your Drupal messages! Combine different animations and override `better_messages.tpl.php` to create your custom look.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Administer > Site configuration > Error reporting (admin/settings/error-reporting). There you have a dropdown list under 'Error reporting' with the two choices you have for the error logging, being:

```
* Write errors to the log.
* Write errors to the log and to the screen.
```

Choose this option --> Write errors to the log

And save